# passar de JQuery para CSS3

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Alguma forma de fazer isso em CSS3?

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
  var ecra = window.innerWidth;
  $(".topo").css("height",ecra*0.293);
}
```

Tentei

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:1000px) {
  .topo {
    height: calc(device-width*0.293);
}
```

Mas não consigo achar o tamanho do ecrã com css

Comment: em css nao t em como unica forma é vc usando vh ou %

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi!

Comment: cara css ou vc usa % nos tamanhos ou pixel ou VH da uma googada mas de qualquer forma para pegar a altura atual da tela so com javascript

Comment: Pois é. O problema é que a cada resolução do ecrã eu tenho um tamanho diferente para uma div

Comment: nao pode usa javascript ?

Comment: não, tentei também calc(device-width*0,293) mas não adiantou. Não deu para recuperar o tamnanho da tela

Comment: cara javascript funciona semrpe usei pra calcula tamanho da tela da uma googada q vc acha: procure por how to get screen size whit java script

Comment: Do jeito que fiz está funcionando corretamente. Mas gostara é de deixar apenas css se fosse possível

Comment: Tamanho do ecrã é 100%. `calc(100% * 0.293)`. Os números dos operadores devem ser separados. Não pode ser junto: `calc(100%*0.293)`.

Comment: o problema é que eu preciso multiplicar os 100% * 0.293 e achar a altura de uma div a partir do comprimento do ecrã. Será que dá certo?

Comment: Só com JavaScript.

Comment: rsrs, tentei aqui, deu não. Obrigado!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tem sim como você fazer isso:

usando no propriedade height a unidade de medida vw (viewport width), para calcular a partir da altura do monitor, se usa o vh (viewport height).

estou considerando que vc quer que a altura da `<div>` com classe `.topo` seja igual a 29.3% da largura do monitor.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:1000px) {
  .topo {
    height: 29.3vw;/*VW é a unidade de medida da largura do monitor*/
    /*height: calc(29.3vw - 50px); opcionalmente e comentado, a forma correta da função calc do css3*/
}
```